# Matlab: Embedding plots within images

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wish to display an image within Matlab and then embed (overlay) a plot relating to the image in the bottom left hand corner. When saving the image to file, I would like the embedded plot to be present.

How can I do this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224532/

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should do what you want:

```
load gatlin
image(X)
colormap(map)
set(gca,'visible', 'off') % turn axis ticks off for the image
image_axes_pos = get(gca,'position');
plot_axes_pos = image_axes_pos;
plot_axes_pos(3:4) = plot_axes_pos(3:4)/2;
plot_axes_hnd = axes('position', plot_axes_pos);
plot(plot_axes_hnd, sin(1:.1:10))
print('-dmeta', 'myfile') % save to a metafile, best for importing into Word, PowerPonint, etc.
```