# Background Image for Plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there an easy way to put a bitmap image in the background of a Matlab plot which does not fill the whole available space und keeps its aspect ratio when the figure is resized?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure to understand what you mean by

> plot which does not fill the whole available space

however the following solution should help you solve your problem (or at least get you started).

Basically read an image (here grayscale) and display it using the `imagesc` command along with the `grayscale` colormap, then issue the `hold on` command and plot the data. Notice that you need to reverse the direction of the x-axis in order to get the right direction for the plot.

Here is the code:

```
clear 
clc
close all

A = imread('cameraman.tif');

x = 1:10;
y = x;

figure

%// Notice the fliplr(A) to reverse the direction of the x data
imagesc([min(x(:)) max(x(:))], [min(y(:)) max(y(:))],fliplr(A));
colormap gray

%// Here reverse the direction of the x axis, otherwise the plot is
%// reversed
set(gca,'XDir','reverse')

hold on

plot(x,y,'--r')

axis off
```

And the result:

[image]

If your background image is RGB, you can use the `image` function: (modified from answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224532/matlab-plot-image-as-background-to-graph)): You need to flip the x data from the image for each channel separately, because `fliplr` only accepts 2D arguments:

```
DataXImage = linspace(min(x), max(x), size(A, 2));
DataYImage = linspace(min(y), max(y), size(A, 1));

%// flip dimensions for each channel
B = cat(3,fliplr(A(:,:,1)),fliplr(A(:,:,2)),fliplr(A(:,:,3)));

image(DataXImage, DataYImage, B, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
```

which, using the peppers.png image, gives this:

[image]

Is this what you had in mind? If not please tell me!

Comment: so @0xy does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
img = imread('myimage.png');

% set the range of the axes
% The image will be stretched to this.
min_x = 0;
max_x = 8;
min_y = 0;
max_y = 6;

% make data to plot - just a line.
x = min_x:max_x;
y = (6/8)*x;

imagesc([min_x max_x], [min_y max_y], img);
hold on;
plot(x,y);
```